# LINQ Select with join and optional where

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have table with **recipes** and table with **recipe categories**. There are diferent **type of categories** in another table. I have **optional** parameter for category, my tables and linq select looks like:

TABLES:

```
RECIPE
recipeId  title

RECIPE CATEGORIES
recipeCategoryId recipeId categoryId categoryTypeId

var result = from r in context.Recipes
             join c in context.RecipeCategories on r.recipeId equals c.recipeId
             where (nutritionStyleId == 0 || c.categoryId == nutritionStyleId )
             && (courseId == 0 || c.categoryId == courseId)
             select new
             { 
               r.recipeId,
               r.title
             };
```

You can only **select by one type** of category(**by courseId or by nutritionStyleId or by none**(if nutritionStyleId and courseId == 0). The problem is when nutritionStyleId  and courseId is 0 then the select return me **all** the **recipes** but **multiply by** number of **categoryTypeId's** in RECIPE CATEGORIES table. So if one recipe have more categoryType's specified, my select is wrong.

So how can I make **conditional** join or something, so when I dont want to search by recipeCategory there won`t be any duplicates (duplicated title or recipeId)

Scenario is that I can search by nutritionStyleId **OR** courseId **OR** nothing(return all recipes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about method syntax (it suits me better :)). But heres the code

```
context.Recipes
.Where(x => x.RecipeCategories.Any(rc => (nutritionStyleId == 0 || rc.categoryId == nutritionStyleId) && (courseId == 0 || rc.categoryId == courseId))
.Select(x => new { x.recipeId, x.title });
```

EDIT:
joining translations:

```
context.Recipes
.Where(x => x.RecipeCategories.Any(rc => (nutritionStyleId == 0 || rc.categoryId == nutritionStyleId) && (courseId == 0 || rc.categoryId == courseId))
.Select(x => new { x.recipeId, Title = x.Translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Language == language).Title });
```

Comment: No problem if you use this method syntax, but now I don't know how can I make JOIN for some table for example for RecipeAdditionalInformation and RecipesTranslations and Users... the join in query syntax is like join t in context.RecipesTranslations on r.recipeId equals t.recipeId and the same for recipeAdditional information, for users the join is by userId ... because in select I need to select some data from RecipeTranslations(title), from RecipeAdditionalInformation(rating, imagePath) and from Users (screenName)  So If i could write that in method syntax, maybe the solution will work

Comment: you can join all other table as i did - with subqueries. i made little edit in my answer.

Comment: maxlego thank you for your help, I have manage to change everything to method syntax and test it. Everythink works just fine ... and I learn some new things... Thanks for help again